# When we raise $f$ to a positive power, what happens to the norm?

Tags: normed-spaces, lp-spaces

I am missing something in the identity $(1.18)$ below.  What does that identity have to do with the fact that the $L^p$ norm is a non-negative number?  The identity $(1.18)$ says that when we raise $f$ to some positive power $r$, we raise the norm to the corresponding power $r$, but now the norm is no longer the $L^p$ norm, but rather the $L^{pr}$ norm.  Could someone explain the relation between those two sentences, or give an intuitive explanation of what is going on?

[image: from terry tao]

Comment: On the one hand $||f^r||_{L^p} = \Big(\int |f^r|^{p}dx\Big)^{\frac{1}{p}},$ on the other hand
$||f||_{L^{pr}}^r=\Big(\int |f|^{pr}dx\Big)^{\frac{r}{pr}}$ is it helpful?

Answer (score 1):

Just write out the norms:
$$\|f^r\|_{L^p}=\left(\int_X|f^r|^p d\mu\right)^{1/p}=\left(\int_X|f|^{pr} d\mu\right)^{1/p}=\left(\left(\int_X|f|^{pr} d\mu\right)^{1/pr}\right)^r=\|f\|_{L^{pr}}^r$$
So in particular if $f\in L^p$ then $f^r\in L^{p/r}$.

Comment: I can see why the identity is true, my question is regarding the author's comment, "the Lp norm is a finite non-negative number, in particular..." and then gives the identity.  It makes me feel like I'm missing the significance of the identity, even though I can see why the identity is obviously true.

Answer (score 1):

I guess the point is that this wouldn't hold if the norm weren't a non-negative number. Indeed if, say, $\| f^2 \|_{L^p}$ were negative, then clearly $\| f^2 \|_{L^p} \neq \| f \|_{L^{2p}}^2$. The argument fails for the same reason the following reasoning fails: $$-1 = (-1)^1 = ((-1)^2)^{1/2} = 1.$$